# MongoDB : Calculating wrongly in mapReduce

Tags: mongodb

This is my collection named logins

```
db.logins.find().pretty()


      "cust_id" : "testuser",
       "created_at" : "2011-03-11 10:31:02.765"

      "cust_id" : "testuser",
      "created_at" : "2011-03-11 10:31:02.765"
```

I am trying to find out Logins of each user based on a Date

I tried this way

```
var m = function() {
    var aux = this.created_at.indexOf(' ');
    emit({cust:this.cust_id,daterr:this.created_at.substring(0,aux)},1);
}

var r = function(k, values) {
  var l = values.length;
  var r = 0;
  var i;
  for (i=0; i<l; i++) {
    r+=l;
  }
  return r;
}

 q = function() {
        var query = {"created_at": {$lt: "2013-04-30 11:19:52.587"}}
        return query;
    }

db.logins.mapReduce(m, r, { query : q(), out :  "userLoginCountMonthly" });
```

I am getting the following Output

```
db.userLoginCountMonthly.find().pretty()

{ "_id" : { "cust" : "testuser", "daterr" : "2011-03-11" }, "value" : 4 }
```

What i see is that the value must be 2 , but it is shown as 4

Could you please tell me why its displaying wrong ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may very well be totally off in this since I've never used MongoDB's mapreduce and I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve in the reduce, but this looks wrong;

```
var l = values.length;
var r = 0;
var i;
for (i=0; i<l; i++) {
  r+=l;
}
return r;
```

If values.length is 2, this will loop twice, each time adding 2, returning 4.

As far as I can see since you only want a count, a simple `return values.length` would make more sense as a reduce function.